# Why does Python return 0 for simple division calculation?

Tags: python

Why does this simple calculation return 0

```
>>> 25/100*50  
0
```

while this actually calculates correctly?

```
>>> .25*50
12.5

>>> 10/2*2  
10
```

What is wrong with the first example?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In Python 2, `25/100` is zero when performing an integer divison. since the result is less than `1`.

You can "fix" this by adding `from __future__ import division` to your script. This will always perform a float division when using the `/` operator and use `//` for integer division.

Another option would be making at least one of the operands a float, e.g. `25.0/100`.

In Python 3, `25/100` is always `0.25`.

Comment: automatically making a division 0? i just spent an hour debugging that

Comment: google deep learning vm, the environment is all setup on python 2, locally i have python 3 and this was baffling me

Answer (score 20):

This is a problem of integer **truncation** (i.e., any fractional parts of a number are discarded). So:

`25 / 100` gives `0`

However, as long as *at least one* of the operands in the division is a float, you'll get a float result:

`25 / 100.0` or `25.0 / 100`  or `25.0 / 100.0` all give `0.25`

Comment: How would one do this in case that the numbers are stored in a variable? For example x / y, where x = 4 and y = 3. Or x = someObject.size.

Comment: One way to do it is tp multiply one of the numbers by 1.0. E.g., `1.0 * x / 2` or you could do `float(x) / 2` - there might be other ways, but these come to mind off the top of my head. You can always interactively verify your results before you code them up in a program. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`25/100` is an integer calculation which rounds (by truncation) to `0`.

Comment: Slight nitpicking, it's not so much rounding as truncating.

Comment: @Levon That's a form of rounding, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just by doing this trick.

> (25 * 1.0) / 100 * 50

So, (1.0) makes sure that the numerator be float type

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 returns zero for integer division if result is less than 1.

Solution is to convert one of the integers to float e.g.

```
float(25)/100*50
```

Answer (score -4):

- In Python 2: 25/100 is an integer division by default
- In Python 3: 25/100 is always 0.25.