# asin function isn't working in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to write code for this function, but I can't get `asin` to work in python 2.7. any ideas why?

```
import math
from decimal import *

def main():
    H = raw_input ("Please enter hight:")
    H = int(float(H))
    m = raw_input ("Please enter crest thickness:")
    m = int(float(m))
    n = raw_input ("Please enter base thikness:")
    n = int(float(n))

    Fx = 0.0
    Fy = 0.0
    Magnitude = 0.0
    Direction = 0.0

p = 1000 #dencity
g = 9.81 #gravity

R = math.sqrt(H*H + n*n)
#Force in x direction
Fx = (-p*g*m*(H*H))/2.0
#Force in y direction
Fy = -p*g*R*(((math.asin(n/H))/2.0)-sin((2*math.asin(n/H))/4.0))

#Overall force
Direction = math.atan(Fy/Fx)
Magnitude = sqrt(Fx*Fy + Fy*Fy)

print ("The force magnitude is", Magnitude)
print ("The force direction is", Direction)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't get asin to work`? What makes you think that it is not working?

Comment: Dividing integer by integer returns integer in Python < 3.0. Read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: @MichaelButscher: You should probably write that up as an answer, because it's almost certainly the OP's only problem here. (That's assuming "not working" means something like "returning `0.0` for perfectly reasonable inputs", but it seems likely.)

Answer (score 1):

Dividing integer by integer (as you do with `n/H` inside `math.asin(n/H)`) returns an integer (which is the floor value of the division result) in Python before 3.0. You must either convert at least one operand to `float` or declare at the beginning of the Python source file

`from __future__ import division`

Read http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238 for details

Answer (score 0):

## Code Corrections

There are a few problems:

1. There is no built-in `sin`, it needs to be used from [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) as [`math.sin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin)

   ```
   ---> 23 Fy = -p*g*R*(((math.asin(n/H))/2.0)-sin((2*math.asin(n/H))/4.0))

   NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
   ```
2. There is [zero division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10768737/2087463).

   ```
   ---> 26 Direction = math.atan(Fy/Fx)

   ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
   ```

   This originates from `n/H` integer division as @MichaelButscher [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053083/2087463).
3. There is no `sqrt` built-in, also use [`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt)

   ```
   ---> 30 Magnitude = sqrt(Fx*Fy + Fy*Fy)

   NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
   ```
4. If the inputs are `float`s they are truncated to `int`s, this seem unnecessary.

Final corrected code:

```
import math
from decimal import *
from __future__ import division

H = 10.0 # raw_input("Please enter hight:")
H = float(H)
m = 0.2 # raw_input("Please enter crest thickness:")
m = float(m)
n = 2.0 # raw_input("Please enter base thikness:")
n = float(n)

Fx = 0.0
Fy = 0.0
Magnitude = 0.0
Direction = 0.0

p = 1000 #dencity
g = 9.81 #gravity

R = math.sqrt(H*H + n*n)
#Force in x direction
Fx = (-p*g*m*(H*H))/2.0
#Force in y direction
Fy = -p*g*R*(((math.asin(n/H))/2.0)-math.sin((2*math.asin(n/H))/4.0))

#Overall force
Direction = math.atan(Fy/Fx)
Magnitude = math.sqrt(Fx*Fy + Fy*Fy)

print ("The force magnitude is", Magnitude)
print ("The force direction is", Direction)
```

---

```
('The force magnitude is', 1291.77652735702)
('The force direction is', 0.00017336501979739458)
```