# How to perform addition and division in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the sum of all numbers within a list. My code is shown below; however, I am getting an error when I try to run it:

```
c = [795557,757894,711411,556286,477322,426243,361643,350722]
for c1 in c:
   x = x + c1
```

I am also trying to divide one number by another. However, the result is always zero:

```
y=(273591/21247633)*100
```

Comment: Give try to ´x=x+c1´

Comment: Also indent correctly, also don't try to divide an integer by a tuple, also be aware of integer division. Maybe follow a tutorial?

Comment: @jonrsharpe:when we perform y=(273591/21247633)*100.it will shown only 0 why?

Comment: @AtuTha see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10768724/3001761

Comment: those numbers are assumed as integers.. the calcualation as float y=(float(273591)/float(21247633))*100

Comment: @Milind you only need to convert the numerator *or* the denominator, and if you're using literals adding `.0` is fewer characters!

Comment: In Python 3 the `/` does the right thing already!

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you need to define `x` before you use it and use `c1` instead of `c`:

```
x = 0
c=[795557,757894,711411,556286,477322,426243,361643,350722]
for c1 in c:
    x=x+c1
print x
```

You can try this code online [here](http://codepad.org/0C0nfi0A).

---

In the second case, you need to [use floating point numbers](http://codepad.org/FfqIghfv) instead of integers:

```
y=(273591/21247633.0)*100
print y
```

This is because the result of an integer-integer division in Python 2.x is *also* an integer. In this case, `273591 ÷ 21247633 = 0.0128763048571` so the result is rounded down to `0`.

[This has changed in Python 3.x](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), and you can enable the same behavior in Python 2.x as follows:

```
from __future__ import division
y=(273591/21247633)*100
print y
```

Comment: Or use Python 3 which defaults to floating point division anyhow.

Comment: True, but this question is tagged as Python 2.7.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this behaviour is fixed on Python 3, and beginners should be probably using it instead of Python 2 if they're doing tutorial-level learning.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I'm not sure it's "fixed" more than changed but I agree about [using python3 unless there's express reason not to](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: And thanks @GoBusto for the `from __future__ import division` change. I didn't know that one.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `x` to `0` and this statement should be  `x = x + c1` and not `x = x + c`

Probably those numbers are used as integers. Using their float value should help.

```
 y = (float(273591)/21247633)*100
```

Comment: what is the reason for -1?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'd guess that it's because (A) you only answered half of the question, and (B) You didn't explain *why* your answer works. What you've written in correct, though, and is arguably more explicit than simply adding `.0` on the end of the number.

Comment: I would guess that the the down-vote is due to the fact that you just posted a snippet of corrected code without any explanation what was wrong in the first place. Also, it answers only half of the question.

Comment: The other half I gave in comments ... I will update my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a **sum** of numbers in a list, then use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
c = [795557,757894,711411,556286,477322,426243,361643,350722]
x = sum(c)
```

For the second one, `int/int` returns an `int` rounded down, so `273591/21247633` returns `0`. Convert one (or all) of the numbers to float and it will work as awaited:

```
y = (273591. / 21247633.) * 100.
```