# Simple Python calculation is wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, floating-point, division

Now this could be me being **very** stupid here but please see the below code.

I am trying to work out what percentage of my carb goal I've already consumed at the point I run the script. I get the totals and store them in `carbsConsumed` and `carbsGoal`. `carbsPercent` then calculates the percentage consumed. However, `carbsPercent` returns 0 each time. Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import myfitnesspal
from datetime import datetime

username = 'someusername'
password = 'somepassword'

date = datetime.now()


client = myfitnesspal.Client(username, password)
day = client.get_date(date.year, date.month, date.day)
#day = client.get_date(2015,11,12)

carbs = 'carbohydrates'

carbsConsumed = day.totals[carbs]
carbsGoal = day.goals[carbs]
carbsPercent = (carbsConsumed / carbsGoal) * 100

print 'Carbs consumed: ' + str(carbsConsumed)
print 'Carbs goal: ' + str(carbsGoal)
print 'Percentage consumed: ' + str(carbsPercent)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 carbsPercent = (float(carbsConsumed) / carbsGoal) * 100
```

The problem is that in Python 2.7, the default division mode is integer division, so 1000/1200 = 0.  The way you force Python to change that is to cast at least one operand IN THE DIVISION operation to a float.

Comment: Or `100. * carbsConsumed / carbsGoal`

Comment: Correct, but that only works because the `100.` is first.  It will not work if you use the order from the OP's code.

Comment: I believe alvas's solution below, of using the float division operator, clutters the code less, and will go away naturally when upgrading to python3.

Answer (score 4):

For easily portable code, in `python2`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10768737/610569:

```
from __future__ import division
carbsPercent = (carbsConsumed / carbsGoal) * 100
```

E.g.

```
$ python
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 6 / 5
1.2

$ python3
>>> 6 / 5
1.2
```