# Mathematics and behavior with floats vs ints

Tags: python, math, numbers

This is driving me mad...  Of all the years I've been using python, this is just now starting to present itself.  How I managed to dodge it up until now is beyond me.

If you open a python idle and try this equation...

```
4/32*100
```

You'll get '0' as an answer.  Now try the same equation using floats....

```
4.0/32.0*100.0   (or just the first number 4.0/32*100)
```

You now get an actual percentage.

WTF!?

Is this some kind of python error!?  Even a calculation can do the equation and spit out a percentage.

So why can't python see a 4 as 4.0.  Better question...  What is the interpreter actually seeing if it's not seeing a 4(4.0)?

Someone please clear this up so I can feel professional with python again (lol).

Comment: Are you trying to divide 4/32 and then multiply by 100? If so, cant replicate.

Comment: Are you using Python 2?  If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768724/why-does-python-return-0-for-simple-division-calculation.  TL;DR - integer division rounds values less than 1 to 0.

Comment: Works for me OK, using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 2.x, dividing two integers or longs uses integer division, also known as "floor division"(applying the floor function after division)

For Python 3.x, "/" does "true division" for all types.

To make python perform true division, cast any of the denominator for numerator to become float.

```
float(4)/32*100
```

or

```
4/float(32)*100
```

or doing below to make python 2 division behave like python 3 division

```
from __future__ import division
4/32*100
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, `int` type division ignores the decimal values of the division.

For example, 1/2 = 0.5, but in `int` type division, 1/2 will evaluate to 0 because it ignores the decimal values.

Thus, in your case with `4/32*100`, `4/32`will first evaluate to 0 and then `0*100` will finally equal 0.

On the other hand, in `float` type division, it will evaluate answers as we would expect (not in a strictly precise definition though, look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for further information).